How to calculate the maturity date for a Single Name CDS with 5 year Tenor?
Struggle to understand how the new convention works. If there is a Single Name CDS with 5 Year tenor traded on Sept 3, 2023, what the maturity should be?
Based on my understanding, it should be Sept 20, 2028;however, since the standard maturity date can now only be either June 20 or Dec 20, the actual maturity will then move to Dec 20, 2028.
However, from the ISDA doc (https://www.isda.org/a/vGiDE/amend-single-name-on-the-run-frequency-faq-revised-as-of-12-10.pdf), the table is telling me it should be June 20, 2028.
Can someone please help me to understand?
Thanks a lot,
Iong

According to https://www.isda.org/2015/07/07/amending-when-single-name-cds-roll-to-new-on-the-run-contracts/, single-name contracts roll semi-annually, March 20 and September 20. On September 20, we start trading the swap maturing December 20 in 5 years, and do so until March 20. From March 20 to September 20, we trade the swap maturing June 20 in 5 years. Therefore, on September 3, 2023 we trade a swap maturing June 20, 2028, and on September 23, 2023, we trade a swap maturing December 20, 2028. Before the 2015 change, the maturity of the swap traded on September 3 would have been September 20, 2028. Following the 2015 change, March and September are no longer standard maturities.
The immy dates for indices are the same. The quarterly dates for protection payments are March 20, June 20, September 20, and December 20.
Related: What is zero month tenor of CDS?

Thanks a lot for the answer.
